# Converting postscript file to pdf not working

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, postscript

Update:
Sample of the excel data I'm trying to pdf and the pdf file that is usually created below
Excel - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlsBQ.jpg
PDF - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DEHh.jpg

The problem seems to be that the process isn't detecting any content in the worksheet - any advice on how I can 'activate' the content?

-

I have a VBA macro that converts an excel report to PDF files - I want to replicate the code across several workbooks but when I do it works in some workbook and not others.

The code is below - I update the four Const values in each to the relevant cell / value for each workbook and I've checked that the same references are selected in each workbook.

When I run the code it loops through, changing the index cell and produces a PDF with the new data. In one of the workbooks though the PDFs are not being created, I have stepped through the code and it creates the postscript file but does not convert it to PDF.

```
Public Sub ExportGraphs()

Const indexCell = "B55"
Const totalCell = "D55"
Const authorityName = "B5"
Const fileName = "Civic cultural and community venues performance indicator standings report 2013-14 - "

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim i As Integer

Dim awb As Workbook
Set awb = ThisWorkbook

Dim myPDF As PdfDistiller
Set myPDF = New PdfDistiller

For i = 1 To awb.Worksheets("PIN").Range(totalCell).Value

awb.Worksheets("PIN").Range(indexCell).Value = i

Dim strGraphLoc, strPIN As String

strPIN = awb.Sheets("PIN").Range(authorityName).Value & " " &   awb.Worksheets("PIN").Range("B6").Value

strGraphLoc = awb.Path & "/"

Dim PSFileName As String
Dim PDFFileName As String

PSFileName = strGraphLoc & fileName & strPIN & ".ps"
PDFFileName = strGraphLoc & fileName & strPIN & ".pdf"

'Print the Excel range to the postscript file
awb.Sheets("PIN").PrintOut copies:=1, from:=1, preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Acrobat Distiller", printtofile:=True, collate:=True, prtofilename:=PSFileName

'Convert the postscript file to .pdf

myPDF.FileToPDF PSFileName, PDFFileName, ""

Kill PSFileName
Kill strGraphLoc & fileName & strPIN & ".log"

Next i

Set myPDF = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.ShowWindowsInTaskbar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't for the life of me work out why it works in some and not others.

In the workbook I am having trouble with, a 0kb postscript file is created and a text file which states:

> %%[ Warning: Empty job. No PDF file produced. ] %%

Comment: Maybe you should add a link to one of the postscript files that fail to convert to PDF

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post with details of what is produced by the code that doesn't work

Comment: Looks to me like your 'print' is producing a 0Kb (empty, just as the text file produced by Distiller says) PostScript file, which mean its contains nothing, and so, unsurprisingly, fails to convert to a PDF file. I know nothing about VBA, but I'd guess that awb.Sheets("PIN") is empty.

Comment: I've had a similar issue when trying to export graphs where it doesn't pick up the content, there is definitely content in the sheet, attached is a sample of the excel sheet i'm trying to pdf and a sample of the pdf files that are usually produced by the VBA - excel sheet: http://imgur.com/lnE1VER. pdf sample: http://imgur.com/yNDHFMv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tearing my hair out and failing to find a solution for almost 6 months my colleague has just sussed it - the file name of the PDF we were trying to create was too long, we shortened and it works fine now!

I'm going for a lie-down

Answer (score 0):

To start with the obvious: a 0-byte PostScript language file contains no graphics, so Distiller cannot convert it into a meaningful PDF file. So, why is the Postscript language file 0 bytes long?

Something is failing with printing from the problem spreadsheet.

Take VBA out of the problem. Try printing from the problem spreadsheet via the Excel "Print" menu item. Print to PostScript and non-PostScript printers. I suspect that will fail also.

Diagnose the printing failure. Once the "Print" menu item works, I suspect the VBA script will also.